# I want to add double quotes in one of numeric column in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have to export some data from the CSV file and i want columns data in double quote while printing or returning as a JSON data to any http POST API.
I have below data in my CSV file. so numeric value like - 1140.87 is not coming double quote, when I am checking it dtype , so it is object only , so I want all values of these columns in Double quote `""`.

I already tried these optional properties of pd.read_csv:-

```
(skipinitialspace = True, quotechar = '"', quoting=5, sep=',\s+')
```

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\shubham\\Desktop\\MasterData.csv")
print(df)
```

Current Output-

```
{"invoiceDate":"18/08/2019","amount":1140.87, "ID":1234, "promotionType":"Temporary"}
```

Expected Output-

```
{"invoiceDate":"18/08/2019","amount":"1140.87", "ID":"1234", "promotionType":"Temporary"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this line of python code, I was able to resolve above problem for entire list.

```py
df["agreedMechanics"] = [str(v) for v in df["agreedMechanics"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, you could use `quoting=1` for `QUOTE_ALL`, which should quote numeric column as well.

Comment: I tried this, not working in my case, not able to understand why.                                     
      df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\shubham.f.jain\\Desktop\\MasterData.csv", quoting=1)